# How to calculate number of True in multi series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple series as below

```
import pandas as pd

ser1 = pd.Series([True, True, False, True, False], index=['John', 'Alice', 'Lisa', 'Flank', 'King'])
ser2 = pd.Series([True, False, False, False, True], index=['John', 'Alice', 'Lisa', 'Flank', 'King'])
ser3 = pd.Series([False, True, False, False, True], index=['John', 'Alice', 'Lisa', 'Flank', 'King'])
```

I want to calculate True number for every row, for example John has two True result Lisa got zero.
Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Let us do `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([ser1,ser2,ser3],axis=1).sum(axis=1)
John     2
Alice    2
Lisa     0
Flank    1
King     2
dtype: int64
```